# Bootstrap Layout - Move down the heading

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am not good in HTML/CSS as I would like to be so I need your help. It's just simple problem.
I am using Bootstrap and this is what I get on my page(header).
[image]

But I want something like this(move it down, title padding 30px(e.g.) from left and bottom):
[image]

Here is my header section HTML code:

```
    <header class="business-header" style="background: url('http://localhost/img/clanok.jpg')">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1 class="tagline">Article name</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

And here's CSS for "business-header" and "tagline"(other classes are from bootstrap):

```
.business-header {
    height: 300px;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}
.tagline {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: #fff;
}
```

I hope you'll help me: :(

Comment: if you'd provide some JSFiddle code, I'd help you. Or just see the overall idea below in my reply.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rsfktojh/ .. None of those answers below do not work properly..

Comment: if you have the fixed header height, then this solution might help you https://jsfiddle.net/h853f08m/ .

Comment: I set position relative into business-header and position absolute into tagline, moved tagline into div instead of h1 and it works great.. here is [screenshot](http://img.janforman.com/?id=Untitled2evgn.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved class "tagline" into div from h1 and thanks to Frank  Egan(css change) it works great. Heres solution:

```
<header class="business-header" style="background: url('http://localhost/img/clanok.jpg')">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 tagline">
                <h1>Article name</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

CSS

```
.business-header {
    position: relative;
    height: 300px;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}
.tagline {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    text-shadow: 0 0 25px #000;
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 0 10px 50px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
.business-header {
    position: relative;
}

.tagline {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you looking for ! ***[WORKING DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/XD4Ft91mrO)***

```css
.business-header {
  height: 300px;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}
.tagline {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<header class="business-header" style="background: url('http://localhost/img/clanok.jpg')">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h1 class="tagline">Article name</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: EDIT: Nope it doesnt work. It fixes tagline into bottom of browser, not "business-header".

Comment: position: fixed? are you serious?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood you here's what you need thanks to @AdamVáclav http://www.bootply.com/CXrOUR9D7z